# Why Scala runtime reflection no longer works on lambda?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect, scala-2.12

The following simple code:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class RuntimeMirrorSpike extends FunSpec {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.universe._

  it("can reflect lambda") {

    val ll = { v: String =>
      v.toInt
    }

    val clazz = ll.getClass
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader)

    val sym = mirror.classSymbol(clazz)

    print(sym)
  }
}
```

used to work perfectly on Scala 2.11. But now it breaks on Scala 2.12:

```
assertion failed: no symbol could be loaded from class <...>.spike.RuntimeMirrorSpike$$Lambda$124/78204644 in package spike with name RuntimeMirrorSpike$$Lambda$124/78204644 and classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: no symbol could be loaded from class <...>.spike.RuntimeMirrorSpike$$Lambda$124/78204644 in package spike with name RuntimeMirrorSpike$$Lambda$124/78204644 and classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.throwAssertionError(SymbolTable.scala:184)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToScala1(JavaMirrors.scala:1061)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.$anonfun$classToScala$1(JavaMirrors.scala:1019)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.$anonfun$toScala$1(JavaMirrors.scala:130)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.$anonfun$toScala$1(TwoWayCaches.scala:50)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.toScala(TwoWayCaches.scala:46)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.toScala(JavaMirrors.scala:128)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToScala(JavaMirrors.scala:1019)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classSymbol(JavaMirrors.scala:231)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classSymbol(JavaMirrors.scala:68)
```

What is going on here? What kind of object doesn't have a runtime class?

Comment: `val ll = new (String => Int) {
      override def apply(v1: String): Int = v1.toInt
    }` works. SO is not a proper place to report about bugs. Bugs should be reported here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot @DmytroMitin, I'm not sure if it is deliberately lacking a symbol (I suspect not as in which case it will throw a ReflectionError instead of an AssertionError). Will be curious to report and watch the response :)

Answer (score 5):

The encoding of lambdas changed in 2.12 relative to 2.11.  See [the 2.12.0 release notes](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#object-initialization-locks-and-lambdas).

Before, lambdas were encoded in a way that's basically equivalent to Dmytro Mitin's answer as objects that extend a `FunctionN` and have an `apply` method.

In Java 8, lambdas were introduced, but in a slightly different way from Scala.  The `java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetaFactory.metafactory` bootstrap method is called which will be create a class at runtime with one method which calls a method in another class.

In Scala 2.12, the encoding of Scala lambdas moved to match the Java implementation (likely because the JVM (especially HotSpot) recognizes that the result of the `LambdaMetaFactory.metafactory` result is a lambda and does more optimization than it otherwise would).  However, the resulting class at runtime appears to not be mappable into a Scala class, causing Scala's reflection to blow up.

EDIT: the only fix apparent to me would be to manually encode lambdas as instances of `FunctionN`, after Dmytro Mitin's comment:

```
def delambdafy[Result](ll: () => Result): Function0[Result] = new Function0[Result] { def apply(): Result = ll() }

def delambdafy[In, Result](ll: In => Result): Function1[In, Result] =
  new Function1[In, Result] { def apply(in: In): Result = ll(in) }
```

And so forth for the necessary arities...

Adapting your code for a REPL, this works:

```
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._         // Effectively what is being imported with your Spark import

def delambdafy[In, Result](ll: In => Result): Function1[In, Result] = new Function1[In, Result] { def apply(in: In): Result = ll(in) }

val ll: String => Int = { v: String => v.toInt }

val clazz = delambdafy(ll).getClass

val symbol = runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader).classSymbol(clazz)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
delambdafy: [In, Result](ll: In => Result)In => Result
ll: String => Int = $$Lambda$5162/1405722527@114a083b
clazz: Class[_ <: String => Int] = class $anon$1
symbol: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = $anon
```

Whether `$anon` is useful to you depends on what you were actually trying to do which led you to this question.